# Using 2D array to store a portion of a line

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, methods

I have a `.txt` that contains

```
bananas, 1, 15
dogs, 1, 10
cats, 1, 5
```

Using the `split(", ")` method, I was able to get the first `15` in the first row in my array `String[] price` , but I want to store the last two numbers as well. I was thinking a 2D array in which

```
price[0][2] = 15,
price[1][2]=10
price[2][2] = 5
```

and parsing the three as a double and adding them together. I have this,

```java
while ((linePrice = totalReader.readLine()) != null) {
    price1 = linePrice.split(", ");
    if ((line = totalReader.readLine()) != null) {
        price2 = linePrice.split(", ");
    }
    if ((line = totalReader.readLine()) != null) {
        price2 = linePrice.split(", ");
    }
}
```

but it accomplishes nothing because all three of the prices are just the first, `15`.

Comment: no need of 2D array, you can very well put `prices` in 1D array with index per row price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to simply iterate over each line from text file and grab price by splitting line on `,` and append to price array, below pseudo code get you started

```
String[] prices = new String[3];
int i = 0;
while ((linePrice = totalReader.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] array = linePrice.split(", ");
    prices[i] = array[2]; // third index contain price
    i++;
}
```